# why do cx/cy from GetWindowRect(rcWindow2) differ from cx/cy fed into OnSize?

Tags: c++, mfc, width, cdialog, cwnd

I want to get the cx and cy during OnInitDialog of a CDialog.

I can do this with the following code:

```
myDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
  CRect rcWindow2;
  this->GetWindowRect(rcWindow2);
  CSize m_szMinimum = rcWindow2.Size();
  int width = m_szMinimum.cx;
  int height = m_szMinimum.cy;
}
```

However, the cx and cy in the OnInitDialog is not the same as cx and cy which got into OnSize:

```
void myDialog::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
```

From OnInitDialog: cx=417, cy=348

From OnSize      : cx=401, cy=310

looks like might be the borders but i can't figure it out.

Suggestions as to how to get the same xy data in OnInitDialog as is fed into OnSize would be appreciated.

---

Inheritance:

myDialog -> CDialog -> CWnd

Comment: Yes, the difference is the border thickness and caption. Instead of `GetWindowRect`, use `GetClientRect` which corresponds `OnSize` values, it's the width and height of client area, it doesn't include non-client area, dialog borders and caption.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani That's correct and that should be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: You are right Roger. For some reason I forgot the instructions about where to comment and where to answer. At least we are all in agreement :)

Comment: yes, if you put it as an answer, I'll mark it as the official answer.  Thank you for the help Barmak.

Comment: Thanks Fractal. I put in a long answer just to be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetWindowRect` returns window's Top-Left position in screen coordinates. Width and height of window includes border thickness and the height of the caption.

`GetClientRect` always returns zero for Top-Left corner. Width and height is the same values as `OnSize`.

While we are on the subject, this can also get confusing when it comes to moving child windows. Because `SetWindowPos` needs client coordinates, while `GetWindowRect` returns screen coordinates only. Screen/Client conversion will be needed like this:

```
void GetWndRect(CRect &rc, HWND child, HWND parent)
{
    GetWindowRect(child, &rc);
    CPoint offset(0, 0);
    ClientToScreen(parent, &offset); 
    rc.OffsetRect(-offset);
}
```

Now we can move a button in dialog box:

```
CWnd *child = GetDlgItem(IDOK);
CRect rc;
GetWndRect(rc, child->m_hWnd, m_hWnd);
rc.OffsetRect(-5, -5);
child->SetWindowPos(0, rc.left, rc.top, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE);
```